# 起点ページを外のサーバーページにしたい

Tags: monaca

monacaでアプリ開発を初めて行っているものです。

ネイティブ内のwwwではなく、サーバ上のwwwを読む様にしたいと思いまして、onloadでlocation.hrefでURLを呼び出す様にしました。

デバッガーでは動作するのですが、ビルドして実機へインストールすると指定したページが表示されずスプラッシュ画像で止まったままになります。

別な方法で実装が必要なのでしょうか？

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startPage(){
 location.href="http://〜";
}
</script>

<body onload="startPage();">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTMLの準備が出来ても、端末の準備が出来ていないと思います。
スプラッシュはJavaScriptで停止するので、
スプラッシュのロード終了前に遷移してしまうと動作しません。
スプラッシュで固まってしまいます。
下記でどうでしょう？

```
document.addEventListener(
    'deviceready', 
    function(){
        location.href="https://www.google.co.jp/";
    }, 
    false
);
```

もしくは自分でスプラッシュを止めて遷移するかですね

Comment: ありがとうございます！
解決しました！

Comment: 解決したのであれば良かったです。ただ、解決したのであれば解決した回答を採用もしくは、解決した際に用いた手法を新たな回答として投稿してください。他の同じ問題を抱えている方への参考にもなります。